# How to collaborate remotely in rails with different Ruby versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to generate a rails project with a 'minimum' Ruby version?  Perhaps to exclude the version altogether?

Situation: I am working on an introductory rails project with a remote partner (paired programming).  We have a small difference in ruby version (2.5.1 and 2.5.8).

Set-up:
`$ rails _5.2.3_ new my_project_name -G --database=postgresql`

We then update the gemfile to allow 'at least' version 2.5.1:
`ruby '~> 2.5.1'`

Each time we pass the project it requires that we edit the `/.ruby-version` file to `2.5.1` and `2.5.8` respectively.

This `/.ruby-version` change is what I am trying to solve more permanently.

I am new to programming!

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is by just installing the same Ruby version :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the instructors required that I set up on 2.5.8 due to compatibility issues with the M1 processor.  I didn't want to open up a can of worms with that issue, so I sought a solution at the project level.  

Just trying to be conscientious and avoid every partner that works with me from here on dealing with the version issue.

Comment: Use a Ruby version manager?

Comment: It is normal to use one consistent version of software when developing an application. Whilst we could suggest various workarounds, the premise of your question is a bit absurd: Your remote partner should be perfectly capable up installing a different ruby version, probably using a ruby version manager like `rbenv`.

Comment: However, on that point: If you use `rbenv`, not `rvm`, then it's not dependant on a `.ruby-version` file at all - and therefore specifying `ruby '~> 2.5.1'` **in the `Gemfile`** would work for both of you. However, regardless, I would recommend using the exact same version on both machines (and on CI, and on production!)

Comment: (Or likewise, you could add `.ruby-version` to the `.gitignore` and -- like above -- rely on the `Gemfile` to specify the version constraint.)

Comment: All the recommendations @TomLord offered are sage advice; however I would add one other option which is to just remove the `.ruby-version` file altogether, since `rvm` also respects the `ruby` Gemfile directive.

Comment: Thanks for all of your input!  I appreciate the context on version management, it was not a tool I had used yet.  It looks like I have a few good options to discuss with my project partner.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways you could force this to happen (go down the rabbit hole of `.gitignore`ing ruby version, etc)....but *by far*, the best way is to be developing on the same ruby version.